# Validation notice: "Start tag DIV seen in table"

Tags: php, html, validation

I'm getting this error running validation: "Start tag div seen in table"  that results in "Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored".

```
<div class="post">
    <table>

        <?php
        $dir   = 'img/';
        $filetype = '*.*';
        $allow = array('jpg');
        $files = glob($dir.$filetype);
        $newest_images_first = true;
        $files = array_reverse($files);
        $i=0;
        $open = opendir($dir);      
        while (($file=readdir($open))!==false) {$ext=str_replace('.', '', strrchr($file, '.'));if (in_array($ext, $allow)) $list[$i++]=$file; }
        $perPage= 20;
        $total=count($list);
        $pages=ceil($total/$perPage);
        $thisPage=isset($_GET['pg'])?$_GET['pg']-1:0;
        $start=$thisPage*$perPage;
        $pageNumber= $thisPage+1;
        $perRow= 1;
        $imgCnt=0;
        $imgCnt+=1;
        for ($i=$start;$i<$start+$perPage;$i++) 

        { // <---------- this opens element

            echo '<div class="item">';  // <----------- this div doesn't open!!

                // Preloader
                echo '<div class="preloader"></div>';

                if (isset($list[$i])) {

                  echo '<figure>';
                   echo '<div class="photo">';

                    $exif = exif_read_data($files[$i], 0, true);
                    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
                    $title = substr($files[$i],strlen($dir),strrpos($files[$i], '.')-strlen($dir));
                    $title = str_replace( array( '%', '_'), " ", $title);
                    $title = substr($title, 5);
                    $title = str_replace( array('', '_'), "", $title);
                    $imgname = $files[$i]; 
                    echo '<img src="'.$imgname.'" alt="blahblah '.$title.'" onLoad="this.width*=0.6;imgLoaded(this);" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src="bundles/blank.svg";">';

                  echo '</div>'; // .photo

                  echo '<figcaption>';                  

                  $title = preg_replace('/\'([^\']+)\'/', '<em>$1</em>', $title);
                  echo '<h2>'."". $title .'</h2>';
                  echo "<p>".$exif['IFD0']['ImageDescription']."</p>";

                  echo '</figcaption>';     
                 echo '</figure>';          

                            }

                            else {
                            echo "<td></td>";
                            }

                    if ($imgCnt%$perRow==0) echo "</tr><tr>";

                    echo '</div>'; // .item

                    }

                    closedir($open);
                    ?>

                    </table>        

                </div> <!-- post -->
```

I have tried many things, yet I could not find the solution. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: `<tr>`, `<thead>`, `<tfoot>` and `<tbody>` are the only valid direct descendants of the `<table>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you don't use tr and td inside your table? 
div tag inside table tag is incorrect.

Comment: Would that solve the problem? If so, you should give an example.

Answer (score 1):

The div tag may not be a direct child of table, but may be used inside the td tags.  The error message was misleading to me "div tag inside table". It may be "inside", just not a direct child.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<table>
   <div>DIV is not allowed here</div>
   <caption>  This it the Caption
          <div>This is a caption div -- why?</div>
   </caption>
     <tr>  <!-- tr Row 1 may not contain text.  -->
       <td> Col 1 Stuff goes here.</td>
       <td> Col 2 here.</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Col 1 of Row 2 is here.</td>
       <td>Col 2 Row 2
          <div>Sub part A</div>
          <div>Sub part B</div>
          <div>Sub part C</div>
       </td>
     </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Gives the Errors-
Error: Start tag div seen in table.
From line 8, column 8; to line 9, column 8

> ↩↩↩   DIV is

Fatal Error: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.

When line 8 is removed with a comment, the error disappears.
Line 13 demonstrates another similar error-
  tr may not contain text directly.
which now gives the validation error-
   Error: Misplaced non-space characters inside a table.
which is phrased similarly, imho, misleadingly.